# How to load language-specific assets with LibGDX?

Tags: java, android, properties, libgdx, assets

I'm trying to load language-specific assets via the `AssetManager` class and the `I18`N class but I don't really get it. How does that work? What do I have to write in the `MyBundle.properties` file? What do I have to write in my Asset Manager class? And how can I load the specific asset?

Thank you

Comment: what do you mean by language-specific assets. Only language specific assets is Strings that not relate with AssetManager.

Comment: It's explained in detail here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Internationalization-and-Localization